# Debug Screen Flow in Rollback mode

Tags: visual-workflow, debugging, rollback

How can I debug a screen flow in rollback mode?
I can not see that option anymore. I am on Chrome browser. Win 23 release. Can not remember if I previously used to get this, and if this is a release impact.

[image: no Run Flow in Rollback Mode option]

Note, the option comes just fine for Record Triggered Flows:

[image: Still appears for record triggered flows]

Could someone please tell me what I am missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess this is not possible in screen flows. As per the [article](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_forcecom_flow_fbuilder_debug.htm&type=5&release=226)

> 1. Available for autolaunched flows.
> 2. Non-DML statements, such as HTTP requests, are executed and are not
>    rolled back.
> 3. Asynchronous actions and asynchronous DML statements are not rolled
>    back.
> 4. The Pause element and some actions don’t support rollback mode. If
>    you debug a flow with one of those elements or actions, the flow
>    stops before executing the element or action. All DML statements
>    that executed before the element or action are rolled back.

Comment: thanks for pointing me to the right doumentation :)